# How to change table view center label highlighted?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Table view center cell always highlight like a picker. If I select the center cell, that value is return. If I scroll the table at the time center point must highlighted the values only change(like picker action)How to do this? Any sample code for this task. Thanks in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILabel     *modelLabel;
        UIButton    *modelButton;
        modelButton                 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        modelButton.frame           = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, LABEL_WIDTH, LABEL_HEIGHT);
        modelButton.tag             = indexPath.row+100;
        [modelButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(modelButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:modelButton];
        modelLabel                  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, LABEL_WIDTH, LABEL_HEIGHT)];
        modelLabel.text             = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[modelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Model"]];
        modelLabel.tag              = indexPath.row+1000;
        modelLabel.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
        modelLabel.textColor        = [UIColor grayColor];
        modelLabel.alpha            = 0.5;
        modelLabel.textAlignment    = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        modelLabel.font             = EUROSLITE_FONT(14);
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:modelLabel];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The rows count is 700, 800, like this.

Comment: please paste some code...

Comment: Can't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve...

Comment: place a view with transparent color at center of your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UITableView` extends `UIScrollView`. So you can implement the following delegate:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

There you can check the `scrollView.contentOffset` and set the corresponding cell to highlighted. Please note, that's not the center cell. You need to add `(int)(scrollView.frame.size.height/2)-(int)(cell.frame.size.height/2)` on `scrollView.contentOffset.y`.

Example (Please de-highlight all other cells):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [[tableView visibleCells] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y+(int)(scrollView.frame.size.height/2));
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:center];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
    [cell setHighlighted:YES];
}
```